# Configuring asp.net web site to work with any excel version

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (asp.net, VB)

I have a created a website that creates and saves an excel document as part of a process started from a button click.

It works fine on my PC as I have excel 2013 installed and I added a reference to the office 15 object library.  When I try to run it from the server I get the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is because the server has excel 2007 installed I am guessing.  The main user of the site will be using excel 2010 for the moment.  Is there any clean way of making sure my site will work regardless of the version of excel the user has?

Comment: Excel XML? I forget how far back it goes for compatibility (I'd say 2003 but unsure). Server wouldn't have dependency as well (it's "just XML"). Users will be able to open natively in in Excel without "import". Hth...

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with the Excel version for the user. It is because the server (where your code is running) does not have the same excel version that you used for development. Essentially, if somebody answers your question (as written), it won't solve your error.